# How to pick up where migrate_d2d_ui leaves off?

Tags: 7, migrations

I ran into some trouble upgrading a [Drupal Commons](https://drupal.org/project/commons) site to the latest version after it had initially been launched on a beta version of Commons 3. To work around the issues and hopefully start with a cleaner slate, I thought I'd instead try migrating the data to a freshly installed site using the [Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/migrate) and [Drupal-to-Drupal data migration](https://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) modules.

So far, the vast majority of what I need migrated is handled automatically just using the migrate_d2d_ui without any custom code. However, there is one important entityreference field (og_group_ref) that doesn't seem to be getting migrated.

A lot of the documentation and example code seems to be written before migrate_d2d_ui and assumes that you're defining the migration group from scratch. It's unclear to me how to augment what migrate_d2d_ui already handles. Can anyone point me in the general direction for adding just a single field to the automatically generated migration group?

Comment: Usually, you would still write your migrations extending what's provided by drupal_d2d. Are you using the example module? Or maybe Drupal Commons is providing the registered migrations?

Comment: The UI for Drupal-to-Drupal migration adds an "Import from Drupal" tab to the Migration Dashboard that I used to set up the basic mappings for users, taxonomy, nodes, etc. It doesn't let you specify the mapping down to the field level though; it apparently picks up some defaults from the migrate_d2d module. I'm not using the example module. If I'm not mistaken, the example module is for D6->D7 migrations. Sounds like I'll need to use it as reference when extending the existing migrations though.

Comment: Yeah that's the way. Extend the node migration and all you have to do is add your extra field. `$this->addFieldMapping($dest, $source);`